# why can't connect to the mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysql

one: i using this code to connect mysql databse which on a shared host.

```
  <?php

 mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "123") or die(mysql_error());

 echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";

  ?>;
```

the user and password are created by the cpanel.which are the database's user and password.

two: i use this line `mysql -hlocalhost -uuser -p123` in my window operation system MS-DOS  window. but it still can't connect the mysql. why?

Comment: I think you can, it's just an absolutely terrible idea.

Comment: @Elliot, @josh - Yes, you can.

Comment: Normally `localhost` is the correct server (in cPanel environments), but not always. In cPanel, it sometimes gives you the exact connection string necessary to connect (with the password redacted). Go into cPanel click on MySQL Databases, and check to see if you gives you the connect string. Also, check to see if the user has the correct permissions (normally, it should be ALL permissions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to declare a variable. ie `$link = mysql_connect("...")`...
or you might want to specify which db you want to connect to, the db name.

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: It's not necessary to set the connection string to a variable, but useful because you can test that variable for `FALSE` on failure.

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_connect("host_parameter", "user_parameter", "password_parameter, "database_parameter");

```
$link= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root_password","my_database");

if(empty($link)){
   die("Error:" . mysqli_error());
}
```

if it's your first time ( mysql user_parameter = root and password = "")

HOPE IT HELP U